# Weird problem with advect program in fluid simulator

Tags: opengl, physics, glsl

I implemented 2d fluid simulator. Solver runs entirely on GPU. All works fine... on my work PC. But on home PC I have some awful glitches, and I can`t understand how to fix them. Empirically I discovered that problem is localized somewhere in *advect* program. This is very strange cause at work I have integrated video, and at home — NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT. Here is the GLSL source of advect program (some lines were dropped for clearness):

```
#version 130

out vec3 value;

uniform sampler2D q;
uniform sampler2D velocity;
uniform float dt;
uniform float inverseSize;

void main()
{   
  vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy * inverseSize; 

  vec2 np = p - dt * texture(velocity, p).xy;

  value = texture(q, np).xyz;
}
```

And some screenshots.

Work PC:

[image: view of swirling colors like two or more fluids mixing]

Home PC:

[image: distorted view of similar colors, clearly in error]

Comment: It looks like the visualization of a vector field and it seems ok, conceptually. Are any buffers swapped somewhere, or is this just a single simulation step? Interesting question from an interesting field, hopefully someone will answer this. To debug it, I would check if my uniforms are passed correctly: use constants/floats instead of uniforms and see the difference.

Comment: This is just a single simulation step. I have a C++ function Advect(). It takes target texture, quantity texture (q) and a velocity texture. I followed your advice and tried to use consts instead of uniforms, but result is the same.

Comment: Following your update, it kinda means the velocity texture sampler is not correctly sent. I've no idea why that is, but it might require you to use opengl to debug the glsl compiled and linked program. If the velocity's the problem, using `texture(q,p).xy`should do something as well. Another thing is that if there's no texture data, it's zero by default. So try and see what happens also when `vec2 np = p`. If you get your "nasty" output, that's the source of your headache..

Comment: Difficult problem u got there, [P = NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) (joke)

Comment: The advice to check my samplers was very useful. I discovered that something was terribly wrong with my quantity texture (q, texture to advect). In my C++ advect function I have few calls, that passes textures into the shader. So I randomly swapped the calls or more technically changed texture bindings. Surprise, it worked! I have no idea why, it was a random decision. In a dozen of other steps I have the same calls, textures are passed in the random order and no problems. Sorry guys for the dismal ending. OpenGL played a cruel joke with me.

Comment: @iodiot You might have invoked something bad. Integrated drivers can be more permissive than NVidia.

Comment: To me it seems like the problem is caused by some format problem, could you show us how you setup that texture? have you tried visualizing that texture?(talking about the velocity texture)

Comment: Maybe some variables are simply not initialized. Some drivers intialize every variable to 0.0f before some don't.

Comment: Could you answer the question with a before and after? I think it would be highly useful to anyone who meets this challenge in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP's response, substituting

```
vec2 np = p - dt * texture(velocity, p).xy;
```

for

```
vec2 np = p - dt * vec2(0.01);
```

solved the problem. The field and density moves *smoothly* in the `(0.01, 0.01)` direction.